# Ошибка при создании модели таблицы на основе массивов (DefaultTableModel)

Tags: java, массивы, swing, jtable

Коротко, суть такая.
Прочитал из файла числа в двумерный массив, теперь нужно этот массив вывести в таблицу `JTable`.
Как я понял, нужно сначала создать модель и потом добавить её в таблицу, для этого нужно написать что-то типа:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(matrix1, name);
table1 = new JTable(model);
```

Но пишет, что нет такого решения. Как я понял, массивы должны быть типов: `object[][]` и `object[]`.
Скажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать массивы в такие типы. И в этом ли проблема?
Сейчас у меня массивы таких типов: `int[][]` и `String[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Но я уже нашёл решение.

```
table1.setModel(new AbstractTableModel() {
                        @Override
                        public int getRowCount() {
                            return 5;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int getColumnCount() {
                            return 5;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                            return matrix1[rowIndex][columnIndex];
                        }
                    });
```